# nltk tokenizing a 175 mb file

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Does nltk have some serialization format for writing out tokenized text ? I have a 175mb text file and getting it into the `nltk.Text` object takes me 4 minutes (on a macbook retina -- i.e., cutting edge processor, 8 gigs of ram and a SSD). Loading the raw file from disk is instantaneous almost.

The functions that do the work are as follows :

```
def _load_all_text(self):
    if not self._text_loaded:
        file = open("all_posts","r")
        self._text = file.read()
        self._text_loaded = True

def nltk_text(self):
    self._load_all_text()
    return nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(self._text))
```

I can't believe it takes 4 minutes to get done, I guess it's because of the python garbage collector and the list object, which nltk builds on. I don't know much about pickling, would pickling the list do the trick (--i.e., the list in question is the result of `word_tokenise`)?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but tokenization is simply splitting words into smaller bits, so it looks like you could just store it in plain text after tokenization, no?

Comment: Depends on the format, if I write it out as plaintext I'd have to tokenize it yet again.

Comment: Why? I mean if I take a sentence like `Don't panic!`, tokenize it and store the result in plain text, the next time I load it it will still be tokenized, like `Do n't panic !`

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the python runtime environment (data structures and garbage collector) rather than with the actual tokenization. Furthermore, I suspect a tokenizer would still perform a linear scan over the text, therefore the fact that some of the words have been split won't make much of a difference ?

Comment: why would you have to run the tokenizer on an already tokenized text?..